# CBT Hook receiving only some events

Tags: c++, winapi, dll, hook

I created a DLL to hook some events using a CBT hook. It seems to work only for the windows created by the process launching the hook...

My system is Windows 7 x64, but the behaviour is the same also on the x32.

This is the code (sorry but I'm no C++ expert):

```
#include "windows.h"

extern "C"
{
    static LRESULT CALLBACK CbtProcCb(int nCode, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam);
    HINSTANCE g_hDll       = NULL;
    HWND      g_hNotifyWin = NULL;
    DWORD     g_uNotifyMsg = NULL;
    HHOOK     g_hHook      = NULL;

    __declspec(dllexport) HHOOK SetCbtHook(HWND hWnd, LPCWSTR lStrMsg, DWORD threadId)
    {
        g_hNotifyWin = hWnd;
        g_uNotifyMsg = RegisterWindowMessage(lStrMsg);
        g_hHook      = SetWindowsHookEx(WH_CBT, (HOOKPROC)CbtProcCb, g_hDll, threadId);
        return g_hHook;
    }

    __declspec(dllexport) int UnsetCbtHook()
    {
        if ( !g_hHook )
            return 0;
        return UnhookWindowsHookEx(g_hHook);
    }
}

static LRESULT CALLBACK CbtProcCb(int nCode, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    SendNotifyMessage(g_hNotifyWin, g_uNotifyMsg, nCode, wParam); // Send nCode to check the received event
    return CallNextHookEx(g_hHook, nCode, wParam, lParam);
}

BOOL APIENTRY DllMain(HINSTANCE hinstDLL, DWORD fdwReason, LPVOID lpvReserved)
{
    if ( fdwReason == DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH )
        g_hDll = hinstDLL;
    return true;
}
```

Any hints?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When Windows installs globals hook, the DLL implementing the hook function is often loaded in other processes. In those processes, the `g_hNotifyWin` and `g_uNotifyMsg` global variables are NULL. That global variables are only not NULL in the context of the process in which the `SetCbtHook` call took place.

You must have a way to retrieve the correct value for `g_hNotifyWin` and 'g_uNotifyMsg', in an arbitrary process.

Add:

```
const char * g_pszClassName = "MyClassName";
const char * g_pszRegisteredMsg = "MyMessage";
```

to your DLL, and replace "MyClassName" by the class name of the `g_hNotifyWin`  window. See the `RegisterClass` call in your EXE. Update also "MyMessage".

Then, use the following `CbtProcCb` function:

```
static LRESULT CALLBACK CbtProcCb(int nCode, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    if ( nCode >= 0 ) {
        if ( g_hNotifyWin == NULL ) g_hNotifyWin = FindWindow( g_pszClassName, NULL );
        if ( g_uNotifyMsg == 0) g_uNotifyMsg = RegisterWindowMessage(g_pszRegisteredMsg);
        if ( g_hNotifyWin && g_uNotifyMsg )
            SendNotifyMessage(g_hNotifyWin, g_uNotifyMsg, nCode, wParam); // Send nCode to check the received event
    }
    return CallNextHookEx(NULL, nCode, wParam, lParam); // first arg useless see MSDN
}
```

**EDIT:**
As you noted in comment, same problem for `g_uNotifyMsg` See updated function. You could set up those variables in `DllMain`, indeed.

The first argument to [CallNextHookEx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644974.aspx) may be NULL.

Comment: Thanks for the post. I tried with your code (slightly modified because I supposed you used g_uNotifyMsg instead of g_hNotifyWin), but the behaviour it's the same.

Anyway I suppose that if your guess it's correct, it must be valid also for the other global variables, like g_uNotifyMsg. Could it be correct to initialize them in the DllMain?

Comment: I set all the variables in the DllMain to avoid clutter in the callback. It worked, so your guess was correct! Thank you for the help, really appreciated!

Do you think there is any chance to pass these values without hardcoding them?

Comment: I found a way to pass parameters and keep their consistency over all hooked processes. A shared data segment is what is needed in this case:  `#pragma data_seg("")`.

This is the source: http://www.flounder.com/hooks.htm

Comment: I wrote yestersay, than your globals are not in shared memory. Read my comment. :-) But not use pragma data_seg, instead use mapping.

Comment: @cyrusza  If you build complex systems using several global hooks, you may find shared memory useful (data_seg or Shared Memory via Mapping).  For simpler case, don't bother, and learn to work around.

Comment: @Xearinox yes I noticed, I rated the post as useful. Sorry but this is my first try with this subject.

Comment: @manuell thank you for the hints, but I would like to create a DLL more "generic" as possible as it will be used in a scripting language. I just implemented the data_seg and it works a treat!

Comment: I used to rely on data_seg, an dumped them. Go figure! :-)

Answer (score 1):

I guess your ThreadId is not zero, so hook is attached only to the calling process / thread respectively. Read documentation:
 http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644990(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: No, I confirm it's 0. Thank you!

Comment: So problem is your global variables are not in shared memory.